# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable'

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un curso de python básico y no puedo encontrar de donde vine el siguiente error, es de mis primeros programas, entiendo al error que se refiere pero no se como lo puedo solucionar o no veo el error, muchas gracias.

El error es el siguiente:

> 'line 25, in 
> if map_objects[pos_x] == cordenate_x and map_objects[pos_y] == cordenate_y:
> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable'

````
import os
import readchar

pos_x = 0
pos_y = 1

map_width = 20
map_height = 15

my_pos = [3, 1]
map_objects = [[2, 3], [5, 4], [3, 4], [10, 6]]

while True:
    #map
    print('+' + '-' * map_width * 3 + '+')

    for coordinate_y in range(map_height):
        print('|', end='')

        for coordinate_x in range(map_width):

            char_to_draw = ' '

            for map_objects in map_objects:
                if map_objects[pos_x] == coordinate_x and map_objects[pos_y] == coordinate_y:
                    char_to_draw = "*"

            if my_pos[pos_x] == coordinate_x and my_pos[pos_y] == coordinate_y:
                char_to_draw = "#"

            print(' {} '.format(char_to_draw), end='')
        print('|')

    print('+' + '-' * map_width * 3 + '+')
#direction
    direction = readchar.readchar().decode()
    print(direction)

    if direction == 'w':
        my_pos[pos_y] -= 1
        my_pos[pos_y] %= map_height
    elif direction == 's':
        my_pos[pos_y] += 1
        my_pos[pos_y] %= map_height
    elif direction == 'd':
        my_pos[pos_x] += 1
        my_pos[pos_x] %= map_width
    elif direction == 'a':
        my_pos[pos_x] -= 1
        my_pos[pos_x] %= map_width
    elif direction == 'q':
        break

    os.system('cls')```
````

Answer (score 0):

El problema está a la hora de iterar sobre `map_objects`. Al hacer `for map_objects in map_objects` estás redeclarando `map_objects` en cada iteración.

Al final del primer ciclo de tu `while` haces que `map_objects` tenga como valor el último elemento de tu lista, es decir: `[10, 2]`. En el siguiente ciclo del `while` haces que con `for map_objects in map_objects` resulte en que `map_objects == 10` y genera tu error.

La solución es tan sencilla como utilizar otro nombre de variable en ese bucle, por ejemplo poniéndolo en singular con `map_object`:

```
for map_object in map_objects:
    if map_object[pos_x] == coordinate_x and map_object[pos_y] == coordinate_y:
        char_to_draw = "*"
```